# Navigation between two web applications within a single solution file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-3.5

My project have two web application in a single solution file. First web application is based on old architecture and second one is on new architecture. slowly and gradually we are shifting our old application on new architecture.

Now, I am facing a problem while navigating from a page say "Form1.aspx" of first web app to "newForm1.aspx" of second web app.

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

In Form1.aspx of the first web app, add a redirect to newForm1.aspx of the second web app. I'm not sure of the best position for this, probably in OnInit.

```
Page.Response.Redirect("newForm1.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having is that the old web app and the new web app will reside in different virtual directories, so the new web app has no knowledge of where "newForm1.aspx" is because this is a page within the virtual directory of the old web app.

The solution is to ensure that your redirect is prefixed with the old web app's full path:

```
Response.Redirect("http://oldwebapp/newForm1.aspx");
```